# CouchDB Group Level and Key Range

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase

Can anyone explain to me why the following doesn't work:

Assuming the following document structure:

```
{
   "_id": "520fb089a6cb538b1843cdf3cca39a15",
   "_rev": "2-f96c27d19bf6cb10268d6d1c34799931",
   "type": "nosql",
   "location": "AZ",
   "date": "2012/03/01 00:00:00",
   "amount": 1500
}
```

And a Map function defined like so:

```
function(doc) {
  var saleDate = new Date(doc.date);
  emit([doc.location,saleDate.getFullYear(),saleDate.getMonth()+1],doc.amount);
}
```

And using the built in `_sum` function for the reducer.

When you execute this (with group=true) you get results like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["AZ",2012,2],"value":224},
{"key":["AZ",2012,3],"value":1500},
{"key":["WA",2011,12],"value":1965},
{"key":["WA",2012,1],"value":358}
]}
```

Now if you change the query to something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/default/_design/nosql/_view/nosql_test?group_level=2
```

You get results like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["AZ",2012],"value":1724},
{"key":["WA",2011],"value":1965},
{"key":["WA",2012],"value":358}
]}
```

So with that in mind if I wanted to find out all sales in 2011 for "WA" could I not execute something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/default/_design/nosql/_view/nosql_test?group_level=2&key=["WA",2011]
```

This example has been taken from the useful videos over at NoSQL tapes.

[http://nosqltapes.com/video/understanding-mapreduce-with-mike-miller](http://nosqltapes.com/video/understanding-mapreduce-with-mike-miller%20NoSQL%20tapes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always need to give a range of keys, because filtering is done on `map`'s results, **not** on `reduce`.

For example, the following parameters should work (if properly url-encoded):

```
?group_level=2&startkey=["WA",2011]&endkey=["WA",2011,{}]
```

You can read about [view collation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/collation.html) to understand how it works.

Comment: Yep that worked and makes more sense now. Thanks for the link to the ViewCollation guide also.

Comment: I was assuming it was done from the results of the Reduce stage but now understand that its done from the results from the Map function. Thanks for the help :)