# In Couchbase How can we use group level in multi key get while querying a reduced view

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

- I have a reduced view which i want to query using multiple keys.
- Since it is a reduced view so it is processing some data.
- When i query it with multiple keys but it is giving all reduced data separately for each key.
- Is it possible to get aggregated data for all keys i pass.
- Can we use group level with multi key get as i am getting an error when i do.

I have tried with java and aggregating all the keys data in code is it possible to achieve it with couchbase db only rather then in code ?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198720/couchdb-group-level-and-key-range

Answer (score 0):

If the keys of the view are related in a hierarchical way, you can use [group level](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#grouping-in-queries) as you mention.  Otherwise, you cannot query with multiple keys other than to do two queries against different views and then do the intersection at the application side.

I can't speak to why you're getting an error, would need more info.

Also note Couchbase has a developer preview of something that would handle the case you mention.  Look at [Couchbase's N1QL](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql).